# Transforming means/averages into percentages/relative numbers

Tags: r, mean, percentage

The question might be simply, but I am still a bit confused, so any help would be much appreciated.

I am working with a table that looks similar to the following, where I have the base-revenue "Rev0" and the follow-up revenues in all other columns. Also, the last row shows the average revenue for each column.

```
X   | Rev0   | Rev1   | Rev2    |
A   | 100    | 50     | 80      | 
B   | 200    | 20     | 100     | 
C   | 350    | 120    | 200     | 
D   | 150    | 100    | 40      | 
Avg | 200    | 72,5   | 105     |
```

What I would like to create is a table in percentages based on the table above. It should show the follow-up revenues in % based on the first Rev0 column, like this:

```
X   | Rev0   | Rev1    | Rev2    |
A   | 100%   | 50%     | 80%     | 
B   | 100%   | 10%     | 50%     | 
C   | 100%   | 34,3%   | 57,1%   | 
D   | 100%   | 66,7%   | 26,7%   | 
Avg | ??     | ??      | ??      |
```

However, what I am struggling with is trying to figure out how to calculate the last "Avg" row in my "percentages-table". Taking the mean of the percentage-values seems wrong, as the means are not weighted when taking averages of a relative number. Furthermore, simply calculating the percentages based on the absolute values in the first table also seems wrong for the "avg" row, as it does not seem to give me correct values.

This can especially be seen if one column would only contain one value (e.g., imagine that column "Rev2" would only contain the value in row "A"  (80%)) and no other values. Then, the avg/mean should be 80%, but using the second approach would give me a 52,5% (105/200).

Thank you!

Comment: See [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox#:~:text=Simpson's%20paradox%2C%20which%20goes%20by,when%20these%20groups%20are%20combined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first proposed approach is actually more correct, that is calculate the individual proportions (percentages) and then average them to get the average proportion (percentage).

If you feel that the results may differ quite a bit because of sample size (total number of units), then you can calculate the weighted mean where the totals are the weights.